# Module 'psycopg2' "PostGreSQL" not found

Tags: python

I tried:

```py
pip3 install psycopg2, pip install psycopg2,

Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in
c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.8.3)
```

In `test.py` I imported the `psycopg2` by:

```py
import psycopg2
```

When debugging the `test.py` I get results as :

```py
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'psycopg2'
File "C:\Users\DzITC\Desktop\PYFiles\Main.py", line 7, in <module> import psycopg2
```

Comment: Are you sure, you have psycopg2 imported everywhere you need it ? The error is about `Main.py` !

Comment: I was having this issue last night on my Mac!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the Python IDE interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
python -m pip install psycopg2-binary
```

as that would install psycopg2 for your system Python.

Try to run your script with:

```
python path_to_script\test.py
```

I guess you're trying to run test.py some other way, like double-click and maybe you've associated .py files to some other Python executable.

Comment: Why not `psycopg2-binary` ?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.8.3)